# Disable the "IsEnabled=false" Color Change on a Button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, isenabled

I want to Avoid the Color Change of a Button when it gets disabled.
The Button Color should be the Same if its diabled or not.

Using a style I can change the Background Color when it gets disabled:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
...
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        ...
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         ...
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#AAAAAA" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I can change the Background color there, but I want to keep it dynamic because the Background Color is databound and should not change.

If I delete the Background setter, the default background color change is performed.

How can I disable the colorchange? Or at least make the Disabled-Background-Color databound?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it data-bonund most appropriate place, imo, is declaring it inside relative [DataTmplate](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) of your control, where you specify the `Style` (already defined by you) and *data* applied to the control.

There you can define a [Converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) between some your state and relative color you would like to appear on the button.

**OR**

If you would like to limit yourself in `Style`, you can define a databinding inside `Style` itself. Imo not very logical,  but **it is** possible.

Have a look on this answer:

[Change Button Background color through MVVM pattern in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329812/change-button-background-color-through-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf)

Comment: I dont´t get how I can change the Background_Color in the Disabled-State of the button via Style or datatemplate. Can you specify it please?

Comment: @DocSnuggles: did you look on link provided in my answer? There is an actual example of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but hopefully it helps someone. This is how I would setup the style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
...
  <Style.Triggers>
     <Trigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
       <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE" />
       <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#AAAAAA" />
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
     </Trigger>       
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You need to include the TargetType again in the Trigger or else you'll get an exception.