# Access XAML elements from outside class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I made a switch on which the program should change all backgrounds of gieven elements.
Therefore I made a new changer-class (View Model) which accesses every xaml file and changes the background color:

**TheView1.xaml: (partial)**

```
<ScrollView
    x:Name="myScrollView" [...]
```

**TheView1.xaml.cs: (partial)**

```
void switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        if (themeSwitch.IsToggled)
        {
           ChangeBackground.ChangeColor();
        }
    }
```

**ChangeBackgrounds.cs**

```
public static class ChangeBackground
{
    TheView1 tv1 = new TheView1();
    public static void ChangeColor()
    {            
        tv1.myScrollView.BackgroundColor = [...];
        tv1.myButton.BackgroundColor = [...];
    }
}
```

VS then says "tv1 does not contain a definition for myScrollView and myButton". But they are clearly there, why does´nt it work?

Comment: In this way you got a new instance of TheView1 in your ChangeBackground class, but you need a reference to existing TheView1

Comment: yes Pass it over (even it's not a good approach)

Comment: Why not share your approach as possible answer?

Comment: If you are not using MVVM pattern, then you have to create a public method which will set the background colour and then use the public method in your ChangeBackground.cs to change it. Your scroll view is a private object and so it cannot be accessed from outside the code behind file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with WPF try it with the MVVM Pattern and bind the background color.

I found an almost similar question here on stackoverflow: [Change Button Background color through MVVM pattern in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329812/change-button-background-color-through-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf)